# JQM Drop downs in menu header and event handling for each option

Tags: jquery-mobile

Hello i am trying to make a JQM Webapp with 2 drop downs in menu bar something like -

Menu 1                 Title of Page                       SubMenu 1

---

Menu1 has 5 Main options and Menu2 has 5 sub options ,

like if user selects a option from [First Menu ] 5 options will show up in Submenu1 and there will be an HTML page for each submenu. [so total there will be 25 pages] like

Menu1 --Submenu1  --A new page [menu1-submenu1.html]

Menu1 --Submenu2 --A new page [menu1-submenu2.html]

Menu1 --Submenu3 --A new page [menu1-submenu3.html]

Menu1 --Submenu4 --A new page [menu1-submenu4.html]

Menu1 --Submenu5 ---A new page[menu1-submenu5.html]

Menu2 --Submenu1 - --A new page [menu2-submenu1.html]

Menu2 --Submenu2 - --A new page [menu2-submenu2.html]

Menu2 --Submenu3 - --A new page [menu2-submenu3.html]

....................................

How can i do event handling for this?

The following code i have gives me a basic GUI for my task-http://jsfiddle.net/aVkgp/198/

Answer (score 0):

If you setup an array of values for the second menu you can dynamically "reset" the second menu each time the first is changed:

```
var secondMenu = [
        '<option value="1-1">1</option><option value="1-2">3</option><option value="1-3">3</option>',
        '<option value="2-1">1</option><option value="2-2">3</option><option value="2-3">3</option>',
        '<option value="3-1">1</option><option value="3-2">3</option><option value="3-3">3</option>'
    ];
$('#select-choice-1').on("change", function(e){
    $("#select-choice-2").html(secondMenu[$(this).val()]).selectmenu('refresh');
}).trigger('change');//initialize for first-load​
```

This relates the value of the selected option in the first menu to the content in the second menu.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aVkgp/199/

Comment: Thankyou for your reply.I have 2 questions -1)$('#select-choice-1').on("change", function(e){
    $("#select-choice-2").html(secondMenu[$(this).val()]).selectmenu('refresh');
}).trigger('change');**What exactly does this code do??**   2)How can i load different pages each time menu changes??

Comment: @user1721480 **1)** Select second menu element, update it's HTML based on the value of the first select menu element (the values for the first menu element would need to be an index incrementally increasing starting at zero, to match up with the `secondMenu` array), and then refresh the select menu widget. **2)** You'll need an event handler that binds to the second menu, that changes page based on the value selected in the second menu (so it would be a good idea to set the values of the `<option>` elements to an identifier that links to the desired page.

Comment: Thankyou .The following is my updated code .http://jsfiddle.net/aVkgp/201/ .Can you please guide me with a code snippet  as to how to update it to the following conditions like-_if (left dropdown=="1") && (right dropdown=="1") - create an link to 11.html
if (left dropdown=="2") && (right dropdown=="1") - create an link to 21.html
if (left dropdown=="2") && (right dropdown=="3") - create an link to 23.html'_

Comment: Thankyou .The following is my updated code .jsfiddle.net/aVkgp/201 .Can you please guide me with a code snippet as to how to update it to the following conditions like-if (left dropdown=="LD1") && (right dropdown=="RD1") - create an link to 11.html if (left dropdown=="LD2") && (right dropdown=="RD1") - create an link to 21.html if (left dropdown=="LD2") && (right dropdown=="RD3") - create an link to 23.html'